# change text of array item in React: undefined is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to setup the onChangeText function for a TextInput which is a child element of an array, but I get 'undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this2.props.updatePhoneNumber(text)')'

I'm not sure which part I've done wrong so I just paste my code here.
The child item part:

```
class PhoneInput extends React.Component {    
   render() {
       return ( <FormGroup style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <TextInput placeHolder="phone" value={this.props.phone.number} 
                onChangeText={(text) => {this.props.updatePhoneNumber(text)}}/>
        </FormGroup>);
   }
}
```

The father component:

```
export class RecommendScreen extends React.Component {
    state = {
        phones: [{number: "", id: 1}, {number: "", id: 2}]
    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.updatePhoneNumber = this.updatePhoneNumber.bind(this);
    }
    updatePhoneNumber(id, number) {
        const phones = this.state.phones.slice();
        for (let phone of phones) {
            if (phone.id == id) {
               phone.number = number;
            }
        }
        this.setState({phones: phones});
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Screen styleName="paper">
                {this.state.phones.map((phone, i) => (
                    <PhoneInput phone={phone} key={phone.id}
                        onChangeNumber={(text) => {this.updatePhoneNumber(phone.id, text)}}
                    />
                ))}
            </Screen>
        );
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: in `PhoneInput`, `updatePhoneNumber` is not a prop. `onChangeNumber` is but it is not defined anyway.

Comment: @Dez thanks for your fast reply. you are right, a silly mistake. 'this.props.updatePhoneNumber' should be 'this.props.onChangeNumber'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a name mismatch issue, You are passing the function by different name using by different name, From parent you are passing `onChangeNumber` and in child you are using `updatePhoneNumber` that's why it is throwing the error.

Use this:

```
<PhoneInput 
    phone={phone} 
    key={phone.id} 
    updatePhoneNumber = {(text) => this.updatePhoneNumber(phone.id, text)}}
/>
```

Or Inside child component use `onChangeNumber` like this:

```
<TextInput 
     placeHolder = "phone" 
     value = {this.props.phone.number} 
     onChangeText={(text) => this.props.onChangeNumber(text)}/>
```

Comment: Thank you, you are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In the first line, you just need to pass the function to the child component.

```
        export class RecommendScreen extends React.Component {
            state = {
                phones: [
                    {
                        number: "",
                        id: 1
                    }, {
                        number: "",
                        id: 2
                    }
                ]
            }
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.updatePhoneNumber = this.updatePhoneNumber.bind(this);
            }
            updatePhoneNumber(id, number) {
                const phones = this.state.phones.slice();
                for (let phone of phones) {
                    if (phone.id == id) {
                        phone.number = number;
                    }
                }
                this.setState({phones: phones});
            }
            render() {
                return (
                    <Screen styleName="paper">
                        {this.state.phones.map((phone, i) => (<PhoneInput
                                phone={phone}
                                key={phone.id}
                                updatePhoneNumber={this.updatePhoneNumber}/>))}
                    </Screen>
                );
            }
        }
```

In this component, just call this function and pass the value to it

```
        class PhoneInput extends React.Component {
            render() {
                return (
                    <FormGroup style={{
                        flexDirection: 'row'
                    }}>
                        <TextInput
                            placeHolder="phone"
                            value={this.props.phone.number}
                            onChange={(e) => {this.props.updatePhoneNumber(e.target.value)
                        }}/>
                    </FormGroup>
                );
            }
        }
```